# Align text blocks in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with my code right now. I am trying to make a web page. And right now I'm stuck on one point for a while.

I would like to have the following result on my web page:
[image]

here is my source code :
HTML:

```css
    #lp-pom-text-comment-marche p{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      #comment-marche {
        font-size: 21px; 
        font-family: Lato; 
        font-weight: 400; 
        font-style: normal;
      }

      #lp-pom-text-1 {
        width:300px;
      }

      #lp-pom-text-2 {    
        width:300px;
      }
      #lp-pom-text-3 {
        width:300px;
      }
      #lp-pom-text-4 {
        width:300px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="lp-pom-block-content">
      <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-comment-marche">
        <p>
        <span id="comment-marche">Title</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-1" style="height: auto;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span"><strong>1.</strong></span>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-2" style="height: auto;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span><strong>2.</strong></span>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-3" style="height: auto;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span><strong>3.</strong></span>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
        </p>
      </div>
        <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-4" style="height: auto;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
          <span><strong>4.</strong></span>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I start in CSS, and I'm still lost in the different ways of doing. If anyone could give me a track so that I can arrive at the expected result please :)

Thank you :)

Comment: `display:inline-block` on your divs and text-align:center on container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lp-element{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#lp-pom-text-comment-marche p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    
  }

  #comment-marche {
    font-size: 21px; 
    font-family: Lato; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-style: normal;
  }



  #lp-pom-text-1 {
    width:300px;
  }

  #lp-pom-text-2 {    
    width:300px;
  }
  #lp-pom-text-3 {
    width:300px;
  }
  #lp-pom-text-4 {
    width:300px;
  }
```

```html
        <div class="lp-pom-block-content">
  <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-comment-marche">
    <p>
    <span id="comment-marche">Title</span>
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-1" style="height: auto;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span"><strong>1.</strong></span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-2" style="height: auto;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span><strong>2.</strong></span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-3" style="height: auto;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span><strong>3.</strong></span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="lp-element lp-pom-text nlh" id="lp-pom-text-4" style="height: auto;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span><strong>4.</strong></span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <span>text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that what you want ?